# jQuery find first element with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the first element with a data attribute of `data-uuid` inside a table row. I can see examples of finding an element that has a data attribute of a value, but I do not know the value, I just want to find the element with the attribute.

My HTML:

```
<tr id="row_12">
    <td style="width:320px;">
        <input class="form-control has-feedback table_input name changed_event" type="text" value="" data-rowid="row_new" data-msgid="name" data-orig="" placeholder="Name">
        <input class="form-control has-feedback table_input email changed_event" type="email" value="" data-msgid="email" data-orig="" placeholder="Email">
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td class="table_form_cell">
            <table class="table-sm form_cell">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-center form_cell_switch">
                        <input class="switch switch-primary activated_at changed_event" type="checkbox" data-rowid="row_new" data-orig="">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-center form_cell_switch">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_reload_row" data-rowid="row_new">
                            <i class="far fa-sync"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-center form_cell_switch">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_delete_row" data-uuid="NEW_USER" data-rowid="row_new">
                            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-center form_cell_switch">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_save_row" data-uuid="NEW_USER" data-rowid="row_new" disabled="">
                            <i class="far fa-save"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <select class="form-control has-feedback table_input changed_event date_format_id" data-orig="1">
                            <option value="1" selected="">21/Jan/2018</option>
                            <option value="2">21-Jan-2018</option>
                            <option value="3">21 January 2018</option>
                            <option value="4">21-January-2018</option>
                            <option value="5">Jan 21, 2018</option>
                            <option value="6">January 21, 2018</option>
                            <option value="7">21/01/2018</option>
                            <option value="8">21-01-2018</option>
                            <option value="9">01/21/2018</option>
                            <option value="10">2018-01-21</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want a generic way to find first element (rather than using this example's input element, as this is a function re-used for other forms of similar structure.

I have tried this:

```
var uuidElem = $(row).find('[data-uuid]');
var uuid  = uuidElem.data('uuid');
```

also this:

```
var rowId = getRowId(row);           
var uuid  = $(row).find('[data-uuid]').data('uuid');
```

also this:

```
var rowId = getRowId(row);
var uuid  = $('tr#' + rowId).find('[data-uuid]').data('uuid');
```

but `uuid` is undefined. How do I find this element.

Comment: Give  html of row or elem with attribute, please!

Comment: What is your row var? Are you sure you have a valid <tr>? Your code is correct so far. Just add .first() to get the first el.

Comment: The row var contains the table row html selected with `jQuery`. I can find elements of classes or ids OK with row, just not elements with a `data-uuid` attribute

Comment: Can you include the HTML at the Question?

Comment: Hi added. Thanks

Comment: sorry, bad copy paste!

Comment: What is `row/rowId`? Since you haven't added the code that fetches them it's hard to say but I'm guessing they have the wrong values.

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/sedcbeck/

Comment: Let me ask differently. Is the syntax I am using correct? What is the syntax for `row.find.elements.with.data-uuid.present.as.attribute`. I cannot find the answer to this. I find answers to `elements.with.data-value=value`

Comment: Can you reproduce _"but `uuid` is undefined"_?

Comment: @TheRealPapa The syntax of your first version is fine. The problem is we don't know what `row` is in your code. Here's a slightly updated version of that JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sedcbeck/5/ which breaks the code down into steps similar to yours, so you can see more clearly. The problem is, of those, we don't know what your first line does (the one which produces `row`), so there's info missing. Based on your HTML, and for a valid value of `row`, the _rest of_ your code works. So likely the problem is in the code which produces `row`. If you show that, perhaps we can help further.

Comment: Won’t `.querySelector()` grab the first instance on the page, without need for jQuery? Unless I misunderstand what you’re after. `var first = document.querySelector([data-uuid]);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your html hasn't  tag `<table>`,  I add table and next code:

```
 var uuidElem = $('#row_12 [data-uuid]');
  uuidElem.each(function(index){
    console.log($( this ).data('uuid') );
  })
```

All ok. 
https://codepen.io/piotrazsko/pen/RxvBNP
Also , you can try code without jquery:

```
let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#row_12 [data-uuid]'));
buttons.forEach((elem)=>{console.log(elem.getAttribute('data-uuid'))})
```

Finding row without tag `<table>`  not working.